# Integral syntax

Tags: integration

I've come across the following formula.

$
[rx_csinθ - ry_ccosθ + r^2θ]^{θ2}_{θ1}
$

Does this equate to the following?

$
(rx_csinθ_2 - ry_ccosθ_2 + r^2θ_2) - (rx_csinθ1 - ry_ccosθ_1 + r^2.θ_1)
$

I would have expected:

$
rx_csinθ - ry_ccosθ + r^2θ|^{θ2}_{θ1}
$

Comment: if it is integration w.r.t theta then yes.

Comment: I don't know it it comes from an integration function, this is what I have assumed. The title of the question may be misleading. Please see revised post.

Comment: Yes it is equal to the "following" i.e. the 4th line is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these notations are fine. They mean the same thing. The one you're asking about works slightly better in this case because it easily shows that it means for all three terms.

This is assuming that it results from an integral with respect to theta.